# How can I best use UTF-8 for text in Windows program development?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, encoding, utf-8

I've just started doing some Windows programming.

I'm trying to decide how best to handle non-ASCII text.

I'd prefer to use 8-bit characters rather than 16-bit i.e. declare all my strings as char.

I've read the [UTF-8 Everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/) proposals, and I think they misrepresent the current state of Windows.

Since Windows 10 version 1803 (10.0.17134.0) support for a UTF-8 page has been implemented to the same standard as other multibyte character encodings.

I think now that I can:

- Ensure Visual Studio uses UTF-8 to store source code using an [EditorConfig file](https://editorconfig.org/) and use UTF-8 strings by specifying '/utf-8' as [an "additional" option in the C/C++/Command Line](https://learn.microsoft.com/lt-lt/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8?view=msvc-170)
- Make sure the system knows the program is using UTF-8 character strings by calling `setlocale(LC_ALL,".UTF-8");` and/or setting `<activeCodePage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2019/WindowsSettings">UTF-8</activeCodePage>` in the manifest.  (The system will actually expect UTF-8 by default if 'Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support' is ticked in Region/Language/Administrative language settings/Region Settings - I believe this sets the active code page to UTF-8, and is the default for Windows 11).
- Don't define `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` in source, and so use the Win32 'Ansi' interfaces.  Windows will convert any text to UTF-16 internally.
- Use the standard strings and char variables I'm used to, rather than wstring and wchar.

Have I got this right?

**Is there anything else I need to do**, apart from watching out for any code that in some way depends on a single character being held in a single byte?

Or is there some gotcha that is waiting to trip me?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242833/discussion-on-question-by-andyk-how-can-i-best-use-utf-8-for-text-in-windows-pro).